# Can you get Platinum on Easy?

Tags: lightning-returns-final-fantasy-13

Looking at the difficulties on [The Wikia](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Difficulty_Level#Lightning_Returns:_Final_Fantasy_XIII) one of the differences between all 3 difficulties is the Item Drop Quality with Common only in Easy, Common and Uncommon in Normal and all drops in Hard.

Now looking at the [Achievement/Trophy List](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Lightning_Returns:_Final_Fantasy_XIII_Achievements_and_Trophies) there doesn't seem to be achievements for completing each of the difficulty levels or collecting every item but there is a achievement for doing enough sidequests to unlock the 14th day and so far the quests I have been doing mostly required drops which I seems to always get (tattered leather, liquid glass, etc.).

So I am wondering, is it possible to get Platinum on Easy? If not what achievements/trophies can't you do in easy and which difficulty do you need to be in order to pass them?

Answer (score 3):

I very sure it not possible to get platinum on one playthrough. This is because in the guide it talks about needing to play through New Game+.

This is only accessible by completing the game. You need to get to day 13 or 14 and defeat the final boss. Then on New Game+ you need to play on Hard for a few of the achievements such as Aeornite Boss.

Grab the guide [here](http://www.epforums.org/showthread.php?79835-Manual-and-Guides-Master-List) if you want to find out properly, or perhaps you could try [PSsite](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/).